# C# : how can i switch between my two network interface

Tags: c#

can i switch between my two network cards,i need to use on card to send mails so i need to switch control to it.si there a way to do this by c# code?
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you using a library to do the work of sending an e-mail, or using network sockets?  Please edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending email, you will make an outgoing connection to port 25 on an SMTP server. When you make the connection, you need to *bind* the local end of the connection to a specific IP address (corresponding to a specific interface) before connecting in order to force the OS to use a specific interface.  See the [`Socket.Bind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx) method for a way to do this.